# phonegap html5 android synchonous Filesystem IO

Tags: android, cordova, io, filesystems, synchronous

How can I read and write files synchronously, using PhoneGaps Filesystem API?
Is there a an synchronous wrapper available?

Comment: umm. What do you consider synchronous? Filesystem IO is inherently asynchronous, but this is at the OS level. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to access files synchronously through the provided api. Guessing from the way phonegap is implemented i doubt that you can write a plugin to do this synchronously.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way the Java-to-JavaScript bridge on Android works, it is pretty much impossible to do a synchronous implementation of File IO. This is because each Java object in Android that is bound to the JavaScript environment runs on its own thread.

Use the existing [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File) available in PhoneGap - but use it asynchronously. Register a callback with it that will notify your app that an IO process is complete.

Comment: It's too bad that this is the only solution I see... you have to go about 5 callbacks deep to get into the actual work of I/O.

Comment: @jocull through the power of abstraction you can make it one callback deep

Comment: Async is less painful with promises. Choose a promise library, such as Bluebird http://bluebirdjs.com/ :)