# HTML5 Read File Returns Results before File is Read

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am trying to read a text file and return the results.

So far I am able to read the file, but when I try to return the results the results are returned before the file read is done.

How do I force the function to wait for the results?
I figure its something to do with a callback but don't know how to implement it.

```
MyFile.prototype.readFile = function(fileDir, fileName) {
    var strText = "";

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileDir, gotDir, fail);
    function gotDir(dir) {
        dir.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotRead, fail);
    }

    function gotRead(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = function(evt) {
            console.log("Reading " + file.name + " Failed");
        };
        reader.onloadstart = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read " + file.name + " Starting");
        };
        reader.onload = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read " + file.name + " Successful");
        };
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read " + file.name + " Ending");
            endRead(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.onprogress = function(evt) {
            console.log(evt.loaded + " of " + evt.total);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
    function endRead(value) {
        strText = value;
    }
    //returns null value before file read finishes
    return strText;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FileSystem api is asynchronous, meaning you have to pass a callback to your readFile method which will get called when the file is read. It's not possible to synchronously do it, [see this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4854785/1273830)

You can change your signature to this:

```
MyFile.prototype.readFile = function(fileDir, fileName, endRead) {
```

And remove the following lines

```
function endRead(value) {
    strText = value;
}
//returns null value before file read finishes
return strText;
```

Now, you can pass a function as the third argument to `readFile` method and access the file contents using the first parameter of that function.